# How do I add CSS and JavaScript files in a custom module?

Tags: 8

I created a custom Drupal 8 module. I am now trying to add JavaScript and CSS files using the *my_module.libraries.yml* file and the following code, which doesn't work.

```yaml
lrv_key:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/lrv.js: {}   
    dependencies:
      - core/jquery
      - core/drupalSettings
  css:
    theme:
      css/lrv.css: {}
```

How can I correctly add CSS and JavaScript files to pages from a module?

Answer (score 7):

A .libraries.yml file used from a module doesn't tell Drupal to attach the JavaScript and CSS files defined from the library to every page. To attach the library when some conditions are met, a module should implement [`hook_page_attachments()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.4.x).

```php
function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/lrv';
  }
}
```

Using that code, the library would be attached to every page visited from a logged-in user. Attaching the library to every page, even when they are requested from anonymous users just require implementing a hook similar to the following one.

```php
function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  // Unconditionally attach the mymodule/lrv library.
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/lrv';
}
```

The library definition shown in the question contains an error: The *dependencies* key should not be a sub-key of the *js* nor the *css* key, but it should be at the same level of the *js* and *css* keys.  See how Drupal core defines its libraries, for example the ones defined in [core.libraries.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.libraries.yml/8.6.x). (I removed the comment lines from the definitions I copied.)

```yaml
jquery:
  remote: https://github.com/jquery/jquery
  version: "3.2.1"
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.2.1/LICENSE.txt
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js: { minified: true, weight: -20 }

jquery.cookie:
  remote: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
  version: "v1.4.1"
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/v1.4.1/MIT-LICENSE.txt
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    assets/vendor/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.min.js: { minified: true }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery

jquery.farbtastic:
  remote: https://github.com/mattfarina/farbtastic
  version: "1.2"
  license:
    name: GNU-GPL-2.0-or-later
    url: https://github.com/mattfarina/farbtastic/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    assets/vendor/farbtastic/farbtastic.js: { minified: true }
  css:
    component:
      assets/vendor/farbtastic/farbtastic.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Putting the *dependencies* key in the wrong place would not allow Drupal to load the libraries from which your library depends. Your library would work only when Drupal already loaded the *core/jquery* and the *core/drupalSettings* libraries for other libraries.
This and not implementing `hook_page_attachments()` are two possible reasons for your library not to work; another reason could be errors in the JavaScript code or in the CSS code (for example a wrong CSS selector).

The `hook_page_attachments()` implementations I shown use the following library definition.

```yaml
lrv:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/lrv.js: {}   
  css:
    theme:
      css/lrv.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

The name of the library is *my_module/lrv* because it is defined as key *lrv* (the one I used in the code I shown) in the file my_module.libraries.yml (the one you seem to use).

See [Defining a library](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274843#define-library) and [Attaching a library to page(s)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274843#attaching).

#### Note about theme libraries

What I described in this answer is valid only for modules: Themes just need to use a .libraries.yml file. Drupal will attach the libraries defined in the active theme to every page.
That is done in [`system_page_attachments()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_page_attachments/8.4.x), which uses the following code. (See the comment before the quoted code.)

```php
// Attach libraries used by this theme.
$active_theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme();
foreach ($active_theme->getLibraries() as $library) {
  $page['#attached']['library'][] = $library;
}
```

Comment: can you attach using a hook_field_preprocess? or how would you attach only when a field level?

Comment: yup it did work `$variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'module/lib';`

Comment: Note that in themes you don't need to use hook_page_attachments to load the library! (which is weird)

Comment: @AchrafJEDAY Yes, that is correct, but only because the System module attaches the theme libraries in [`system_page_attachments()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_page_attachments/8.4.x).

Answer (score 2):

This is because you've got this formatted incorrectly. Your dependencies are on the library itself, not for the js or css components individually. Assuming you have a js file at `YOUR_MODULE/js/lrv.js` and a css file at `YOUR_MODULE/css/lrv.css` you should update your declaration like so:

```
lrv_key:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/lrv.js: {}   
  css:
    theme:
      css/lrv.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

You can read more in the [Defining a library](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module#library) section of the drupal docs.

One note I'll make is that you may want to define your css under `component` rather than `theme`, but I'm not sure exactly what you're doing. You can read more about component vs theme in the defining a library section referenced above.